# is using services like Grub hub Kosher?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, gentiles, food

Is Doordash, UberEats, and Grubhub permitted? What happens if the food is kosher but the delivery driver is not Jewish?  Perhaps he is carrying pocket ham?

Comment: Is this a question about unattended meat? Could you clarify?

Comment: Do they sell pre-packaged pocket ham now?

Comment: Flagging as rude for the use of "goyishe carrying pocket ham."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly see [Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Deah 118:1,7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.118.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> הגה וי"א דלא בעינן ב' חותמות רק בישראל חשוד אבל בעובד כוכבים הכל שרי ע"י חותם אחד (טור והפוסקים בשם ר"ת) . ובדיעבד יש לסמוך על זה (ארוך כלל כ"ג והגהות מיימוני ותוספות):

(Rama): There are those who say that we do not require two seals except by a Jew who we are concerned about, but a Non-Jew we only require one seal. And after the fact we can rely on this.

> אם שלח על ידי עובד כוכבים בלא חותם אם אותו מקום מעבר לרבים מותר שהוא ירא שמא יראנו אחד מהעוברים ויתפס עליו כגנב ומיהו לכתחילה לא ישלח על ידי עובד כוכבים בלא חותם

If one sent by a non-jew without a seal, if in that place it is travelled by the public, the item is permissible for the non-jew would say maybe someone else saw me and think I'm a thief. Nevertheless, one cannot send by a non jew [in this place] without a seal.

Comment: Perhaps all or most food delivery now a days could be considered private since one has privacy within one's own vehicle? Also since food delivery is so much more common who would even notice someone changing an order and being thought of as a thief?

Answer (score 4):

It is ok if the food is packaged in a tamper evident seal with the mashgiach's stamp.

Comment: Are these necessary or just sufficient conditions?